# Sort lines in txt document based on the last number

Tags: python, sorting

If I have a text document that looks like this:

```
DESERT TROLL STR: 42 DEX: 17 AC: 17
HALF-ORC STR: 19 DEX: 5 AC: 17
EYEBLADE STR: 4 DEX:  20 AC: 12
BLUE DRAGON STR: 40 DEX: 65: AC: 42
SLAVE: NO FIGHTING ABILTIES AC: 1
```

when i read it with:

```
    with open("dndmobs.txt", 'r') as f:
```

I want to sort the lines based on the mobs AC in the end, lowest AC starting in the top and then increases.

```
    mobs = re.findall(r'(?<=\AC: ).*',line)
```

With regex i made a line that selects everything after "AC: " Can I use this as a "identifier" for the lines and then sort them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** to accommodate no whitespace in-between AC: and the number

I'm using CPython 3.5.2

IMHO the re module is unnecessary, assuming that your file will always look as your example. I mean "AC:" will be followed by an integer **at the end of each line**.

#### Code

**Use list comprehension and sorted()**

```
with open("dndmobs.txt", 'r') as f:
    tuples_list = [(line.strip(), line.strip().split()[-1]) for line in f]
```

For the case of no whitespace in-between "AC:" and the number you could use the re module

```
with open("dndmobs.txt", 'r') as f:
    tuples_list = [(line.strip(), re.findall('\d+', line)[-1]) for line in f]

for item in sorted(tuples_list, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(item[0])
```

The above code will generate the following

```
SLAVE: NO FIGHTING ABILTIES AC: 1
EYEBLADE STR: 4 DEX:  20 AC: 12
DESERT TROLL STR: 42 DEX: 17 AC: 17
HALF-ORC STR: 19 DEX: 5 AC: 17
BLUE DRAGON STR: 40 DEX: 65: AC: 42
```

#### Details

**Use list comprehension to make a list of tuples**

Each tuple contains two elements

original line

the integer after "AC:" for the line

To collect the integer after "AC:" assuming whitespace

Remove the car return at the end of the line (strip)

Break the line into tokens and put them into a list (split)

Select the last value in the list ([-1])

To collect the integer after "AC:" assuming no whitespace

Use re and findall to make a list of numbers present in the string

Select the last value in the list ([-1])

**Use sorted() to sort the list of tuples**

The sorted() function receives the new list(tuples_list), and uses the second element of each tuple (x[1]) to sort. As you requested, "lowest AC starting in the top and then increases"

Answer (score 2):

I probably wouldn't even use `re`, just `split`

```
with open('dndmobs.txt', 'r+') as f:
    f.writelines(sorted(f.readlines(), key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1])))
```

Comment: Tried it, it cleaned the entire document, thank god for backup ;)

Comment: Oh, did you not want it printed back to the file?  In that case just omit the `f.writelines` call and save the output of `sorted` to a variable

Comment: thanks man, it did the trick. it's appreciated alot. 
I suspect it wouldn't work if there is no whitespace in-between AC: and the number, is there anything one could do to accommodate that? since some of the lines have a pretty messed up formatting after the export.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner that will do the job:

`'\n'.join(sorted(test.split('\n'), key=lambda x: x.split()[-1])`

First split by a new line character. Now you have a list containing each line. Then you sort this list based on a taking each item in the list, splitting at white spaces and keeping the last item (the number you are looking for). Finally we take that sorted list and join it using new line chars. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
f = """DESERT TROLL STR: 42 DEX: 17 AC: 17
HALF-ORC STR: 19 DEX: 5 AC: 17
EYEBLADE STR: 4 DEX:  20 AC: 12
BLUE DRAGON STR: 40 DEX: 65: AC: 42
SLAVE: NO FIGHTING ABILTIES AC: 1"""

sorted([(int(e.split("AC:")[1]), e) for e in f.split("\n")])
```

output

```
[(1, 'SLAVE: NO FIGHTING ABILTIES AC: 1'),
 (12, 'EYEBLADE STR: 4 DEX:  20 AC: 12'),
 (17, 'DESERT TROLL STR: 42 DEX: 17 AC: 17'),
 (17, 'HALF-ORC STR: 19 DEX: 5 AC: 17'),
 (42, 'BLUE DRAGON STR: 40 DEX: 65: AC: 42')]
```